# Getting a barplot with a fully dark background

Tags: r, bar-chart

I'm trying to get a barplot in R to represent the number of occurrences of a target variable from a csv file. However, the output barplot I get is a fully black picture with lines in between. What's going on with the graph and how do I get this fixed? Thank you

Here is an example of the plot and the data structure

[barplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIAEp.png)
[dput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywZE7.png)

```
dput(head(organics.df,5))

structure(list(ID = c(140L, 620L, 868L, 1120L, 2313L), DemAffl = c(10L, 
4L, 5L, 10L, 11L), DemAge = c(76L, 49L, 70L, 65L, 68L), DemCluster = c(16L, 
35L, 27L, 51L, 4L), DemClusterGroup = c("C", "D", "D", "F", "A"
), DemGender = c("U", "U", "F", "M", "F"), DemReg = c("Midlands", 
"Midlands", "Midlands", "Midlands", "Midlands"), DemTVReg = c("Wales & West", 
"Wales & West", "Wales & West", "Midlands", "Midlands"), PromClass = c("Gold", 
"Gold", "Silver", "Tin", "Tin"), PromSpend = c(16000, 6000, 0.02, 
0.01, 0.01), PromTime = c(4L, 5L, 8L, 7L, 8L), TargetBuy = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), TargetAmt = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you attach your code sample that is resulting in this graph?

Comment: Sure! Here it is: 
organics.df <- read.csv("organics.csv")
barplot(organics.df$TargetBuy)

Comment: @r_agasthya Could you use `dput` to give us an example of your code? You could do `dput(organics.df)` and then paste the output here. We don't have the file so we cant see the structure.

Comment: Can you run: length(unique(organics.df)) and check if this outputs a value equal to the total number of observations/rows in your dataframe?

Comment: @neuron, I've attached the picture of part of the output as it has about 22k observations. I hope it's sufficient

Comment: @RyanMillares, the command outputs 13 as the number of variables and the total observations/rows are over 22k. It does also contain few missing values, if that makes any difference

Comment: @r_agasthya my bad, can you run the command  length(unique(organics.df$TargetBuy)) instead and then compare that value to the total number of observations?

Comment: @RyanMillares it outputs the length 2. It's a binary variable to see if a customer buys a type of a product advertised where 1 is a yes and 2 is a no. And the total number of observations are over 22k

Comment: @r_agasthya try `dput(head(organics.df,5))` and copy and paste the results. We need an example not an image

Comment: @r_agasthya can you briefly check how many "2"s are in that column? If you have dplyr library installed and loaded, you can do this with table(organics.df$TargetBuy)

Comment: @r_agasthya paste the output into your question

Comment: @RyanMillares, this is what I got : > table(organics.df$TargetBuy)

    0     1 
16718  5505

Comment: @neuron, I've just posted the output into my question

Comment: @r_agasthya I believe I've figured out what is happening and have posted an answer with a code example for you, along with images reproducing your graph and the graph it seems you are wanting. hope that helps!

Comment: @RyanMillares Thanks so much! That's exactly what I was looking for. Appreciate it!

Comment: @r_agasthya no problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your barplot code is working as it should be; since your graphed variable is binary, there's a good chance that the white stripes are where the target variable was "0". When the dataframe has a huge number of rows, R's barplot() function will remove most of the traditional formatting to make each column a single black line.

In addition, when passing only a single row of data into barplot, a visualization with two axis, it will automatically make the x-axis the index of the data and the y-axis the actual data value.

Your code line barplot(organics.df$TargetBuy) will make a barplot where your x-axis is the index/position of a value in the dataframe and the y-axis is that value. In this case, it seems your values are ranging from 0-1, with 0s appearing as straight white lines and long black rectangles representing large sections of the dataframe where your graphed variable is 1.

This will cause your graph to look like this, given a dataframe of 1s and 0s:

[image: Your output]

This is the graph with only 15 observations. Crank this up to several thousand and it will look very similar to the picture you submitted.

To answer your original question, if you would like a bar plot to show the number of occurrences of each type, use this code:

```
counts <- table(organics.df$TargetBuy)
barplot(counts, main= "number of yes/no", xlab = "response", ylab = "number of occurrences")
```

You should get a graph similar to this:

[image: What you probably want]