# Add Count Labels on Top of Barchart in base R

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have a barplot to which I'm looking to add count labels on top of each bars. Can someone tell me how to do that in base R and NOT using ggplot2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I saw your last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70040927/getting-a-barplot-with-a-fully-dark-background) I have a bit more detail than others.

Example data

```
structure(list(ID = c(140L, 620L, 868L, 1120L, 2313L), DemAffl = c(10L, 
4L, 5L, 10L, 11L), DemAge = c(76L, 49L, 70L, 65L, 68L), DemCluster = c(16L, 
35L, 27L, 51L, 4L), DemClusterGroup = c("C", "D", "D", "F", "A"
), DemGender = c("U", "U", "F", "M", "F"), DemReg = c("Midlands", 
"Midlands", "Midlands", "Midlands", "Midlands"), DemTVReg = c("Wales & West", 
"Wales & West", "Wales & West", "Midlands", "Midlands"), PromClass = c("Gold", 
"Gold", "Silver", "Tin", "Tin"), PromSpend = c(16000, 6000, 0.02, 
0.01, 0.01), PromTime = c(4L, 5L, 8L, 7L, 8L), TargetBuy = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), TargetAmt = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")
```

To make the plot

```
counts <- table(df$TargetBuy)
```

Here you will need to change the y-axis scale because if you don't the top label wont show

```
b <- barplot(counts, main= "number of yes/no", xlab = "response", ylab = "number of occurrences", ylim=c(0,4))
```

To add the labels you need to add `text()` to the plot

```
text(x= b, y=counts,pos = 3, label = counts, cex = 0.8, col = "red")
```

so the full thing will look like this

```
counts <- table(df$TargetBuy)
b <- barplot(counts, main= "number of yes/no", xlab = "response", ylab = "number of occurrences", ylim=c(0,4)
text(x= b, y=counts,pos = 3, label = counts, cex = 0.8, col = "red")
```

This produces a plot that looks like this. Note that I changed the y axis length to 4. If it was set to 3, the top 3 above the first bar would not show

[image: example1]